# Issue deleting ASP.NET Identity in MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So after looking around for guides and tutorials of how can I delete ASP Users, I found the following code to be pretty neat:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(string id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            var logins = user.Logins;
            var rolesForUser = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(id);

            using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                foreach (var login in logins.ToList())
                {
                    await UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync(login.UserId, new UserLoginInfo(login.LoginProvider, login.ProviderKey));
                }

                if (rolesForUser.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in rolesForUser.ToList())
                    {
                        // item should be the name of the role
                        var result = await UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user.Id, item);
                    }
                }

                await UserManager.DeleteAsync(user);
                transaction.Commit();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

My view looks something like this:
[image]

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = user.UserId }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteConfirmed", new { id = user.UserId })
</td>
```

After clicking "Delete" here, in theory, it should have called the DeleteConfirmed method from the controller called "ManageUsersController". However, it returns this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /ManageUsers/DeleteConfirmed/29ad177f-0285-43d2-b065-109876f270b9

What might be going wrong here? Is there another way that I should write the method in the controller? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on the default codes that .NET scaffold for us.

- You're generating the `Delete` link using an extension of `ActionLink` which needs **link text as the first parameter and action name as the second one**. Your `DeleteConfirmed` action is a `POST` method; you can't generate a link to POST, .NET sees GET methods for links. So:

```
<td>
  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = user.UserId }) |
  @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = user.UserId })
</td>
```

- Make sure you have another method called `Delete` which is a `GET` one, in your controller.
- Add another attribute to `DeleteConfirmed`:

```cs
[ActionName("Delete")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(string id)
{ ... }
```

- If you need to delete the user when you click the `Delete`, you should use a POST form including the user id and anti-forgery token as hidden inputs and a submit button instead of link. But it's a best practice to show the user what they're deleting. That's why   .NET generated two related actions for delete; `Delete` (to review) and `DeleteConfirmed` (to actually delete).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I have created a new GET method called `Delete` like this: `[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Delete()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }` but now the error says: `Requested URL: /ManageUsers` - what exactly should the content of the `Delete` GET method be?

Comment: @Questieme You're welcome. I think that would be long conversation. So I suggest you get the whole idea of how ASP MVC works. If you have another controller which is generated by .NET scaffolding system, definitely have a look. Check ASP.NET docs.

Comment: @Questieme But for now, 1. you don't need `[HttpGet]`; it's the default. 2. You need an `id` parameter for `Delete`. 3. You need to get the `user` by that `id` from your context (DB, etc). 4. You need to pass that `user` to a view file to show it to the user before deleting. 5. View file must have the aforementioned POST form, so when submitted the `DeleteConfirmed` will be triggered.